# Nativescript. Change value of ui component

Tags: html, user-interface, angular, typescript, nativescript

I've got the next XML-code

```
<SegmentedBar  #typesOfServices [items]="types_of_services"
selectedBackgroundColor="black">
</SegmentedBar>

<Label [text]="new_index"></Label>
```

When I change selected Item in segmentated bar, I set index of new selected item in new_index:

```
this.typesOfServices.nativeElement.on(SegmentedBar.selectedIndexChangedEvent, (args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) => {
            this.new_index = args.newIndex;
            console.log(this.new_index)
});
```

And when I make console.log(this.new_index) I see new value in console. But in Label stays the old value. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here -https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/ui-category/segmented-bar/segmented-bar-views/segmented-bar-views.component.html#L4 you will find how to handle `selectedIndexChange` in NativeScript Angular 2 project. Most probably the problem is that you attaching the event with `on()` method and setting new value to `this.new_index` could not be triggered

Comment: Thanks!!! It works